# how to run execlp with arguments from command

Tags: c, shell, exec, gnu

I am trying to create simple program which will run shell commands from arguments, for example

```
./run date +"%r"

 07:56:05 PM
```

but I cant figure how. I try this, but it not working. I am pretty confused and absolutely cant figure how exec works..

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    execlp("bash","bash", "argv[1]", (char*)0);  


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not put `argv[1]` in quotes.

Comment: Can you use execvp instead? That would be eaiser.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant (note the lack of quotes around `argv[1]`):

```
execlp("bash", "myprogram", argv[1], NULL);
```

Note that I assume here that `myprogram` is a shell script. In case it's a binary, you should remove the preceding `"bash"` parameter.

One good troubleshooting technique could be replacing `bash` with `echo` to confirm the command line.

Comment: thanks for answer. I try this sooner, but output of your code is error. example: "./myprogram ls" output "/bin/ls: /bin/ls: cannot execute binary file"

Comment: Remove the first `"bash"` argument - `bash` cannot execute binaries this way.

Comment: but thats what I exactly want, execute shellscript commands from myprogram arguments, not only write it out.

Comment: Again, if you plan to run a shell script, prepend it with `bash` in the command line. Otherwise (if you want to `execlp()` a binary), execute it directly.